# Django Endlesss pagination breaks buttons genereated by endlesss pagination

Tags: django, ajax, django-pagination

I have endless pagination working on my site for posts. 
Each post has a like and dislike button which works using ajax. 
The first set of posts have working buttons but all posts delivered with pagination don't have working buttons. When clicking the buttons they don't even run the ajax to send a query to my `views.py` file but the first set of posts have working ones.

`urls.py`

```
    path("likepost/", user_views.like_post_view, name='like_post'),
    path("dislikepost/", user_views.dislike_post_view, name='dislike_post'),
```

`views.py file`

```
    sort = request.GET.get("sort")
    if sort=="newest":
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-date_posted')
        sort_type = "newest"

    if sort=="oldest":
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('date_posted')
        sort_type = "oldest"

    if sort=="top-alltime":
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False).annotate(like_count=(Count('like_post')-Count("dislike_post"))).order_by('-like_count')
        sort_type = "top-alltime"

    if sort==None or sort=="top-today":
        today = datetime.now().date()
        today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False, date_posted__gte=today_start).annotate(like_count=(Count('like_post')-Count("dislike_post"))).order_by('-like_count')
        sort_type = "top-today"

    if sort=="top-week":
        current_week = date.today().isocalendar()[1] 
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False, date_posted__week=current_week).annotate(like_count=(Count('like_post')-Count("dislike_post"))).order_by('-like_count')
        sort_type = "top-week"

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 4)
    trending_tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:5]
    try:
        posts_given = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts_given = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts_given = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "trending_tags": trending_tags,
        "posts_given": posts_given,
        "sort": sort_type
    }
    return render(request, "users/index.html", context)

@login_required
@require_GET
def like_post_view(request):
    print("LIKE REQUESTED!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        user = User.objects.get(username=user)
        post_id = request.GET.get('post_id', None)
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if like_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists():
            # user has already liked this post
            # remove like/user
            like_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
            #return -1
            return HttpResponse(-1)
        else:
            # add a new like for the post
            like_post.objects.create(post=post, user=user)
            if dislike_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists():
                dislike_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
                return HttpResponse(+2)
            return HttpResponse(+1)

@login_required
@require_GET
def dislike_post_view(request):
    print("DISLIKE REQUESTED!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        user = User.objects.get(username=user)
        post_id = request.GET.get('post_id', None)
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if dislike_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists():
            # user has already disliked this post
            # remove dislike/user
            dislike_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
            return HttpResponse(+1)
        else:
            # add a new dislike for the post
            dislike_post.objects.create(post=post, user=user)
            if like_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists():
                like_post.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
                return HttpResponse(-2)
            return HttpResponse(-1)
```

`template`

````
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
        <div class="infinite-container" id="infinite-container" style="max-width:700px;width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div style="display:inline-block;">
                      <h5 style="margin-left:10px;">Sort by</h5>
                      <select name="sort" class="sort_by" id="sort_by" style="margin-left:10px;">
                        <option value="newest">Newest</option>
                        <option value="top-today" selected="selected">Top Today</option>
                        <option value="top-week">Top This Week</option>
                        <option value="top-alltime">Top All Time</option>
                        <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            {% for post in posts_given %}
                <div class="post infinite-item" style="background-color:#494a4d;border-radius: 8px; color: white;padding:10px;margin:10px;">
                    <h2><a href="/post/{{ post.id }}/{{ post.slug }}" style="color: white;word-wrap: break-word;">{{ post.title }}</a><h2>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="/post/{{ post.id }}/{{ post.slug }}"><img src="/uploads/{{ post.image }}" alt="{{ post.image }}" style="max-width:100%; max-height:500px;"></a>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row-post">
                        <div class="column-post-left">
                            <h4 style="text-align: left;">by <a href="/profile/{{ post.user.username }}">{{ post.user.username }}</a> | {{ post.date_posted | timesince }} ago {% if request.user.is_authenticated and post.user == request.user %} | <a href="/post/{{ post.id }}/edit/{{ post.slug }}" style="color:white;font-size:20px;">edit</a>{% else %} | <a href="/reportpost/{{ post.id }}/" style="color:white;font-size:20px;">report</a>{% endif %}</h4>
                            <h5 style="word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;">{% for tag in post.tags.all %} <a href="/search?type=tags&query={{ tag }}" style="text-align: left;color:red;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;">#{{ tag }}</a>{% endfor %}</h5>
                            <h5>{{ post.comment_count }} comments</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column-post-right">
                            <input src="{% static "memeplaza/rocket_white.png" %}" type="image" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" class="like" name="{{ post.id }}" value="Like"/>
                            <p style="font-size:22px;" id="{{ post.id }}">{{ post.like_count }}</p>
                            <input src="{% static "memeplaza/flash_white.png" %}" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" type="image" class="dislike" name="{{ post.id }}" value="Dislike" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% if posts_given.has_next %}
            <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?sort={{ sort }}&page={{ posts_given.next_page_number }}"></a>
        {% endif %}
    <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({element: $('.infinite-container')[0]});
    $('.sort_by').change(function(){
          var sort_type = $('#sort_by :selected').val();
          window.location = "/?sort="+sort_type;  
        })
    $('.like').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('name');
          console.log("Like button pressed!");
          $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "{% url 'like_post' %}",
                   data: {'post_id': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(response){
                       var score = $("#" + id).text();
                       score = score.split(" ")[0];
                       score = parseInt(score) + parseInt(response);
                       $("#" + id).text(score);
                   }
              }); 
        })
    $('.dislike').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('name');
          console.log("disLike button pressed!");
          $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "{% url 'dislike_post' %}",
                   data: {'post_id': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(response){
                       var score = $("#" + id).text();
                       score = score.split(" ")[0];
                       score = parseInt(score) + parseInt(response);
                       $("#" + id).text(score);
                   }
              });
        })
    </script>
    {% if sort is not empty %}
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#sort_by").val("{{ sort }}");
        });
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also include the **urls** and **views** for liking and disliking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`$('selector').on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events to elements that do not exist yet

```
$('#infinite-container').on('click', '.like', function() {
    ...
})

$('#infinite-container').on('click', '.dislike', function() {
    ...
})
```

Using `$('.like').click` will only bind the event handler to elements that currently exist on the page

Comment: I just changed my code to this but it still didn't work. newly generated buttons are still not getting called by ajax.

Comment: it seems jQuery is going off of an outdated tree of elements on the page. Is there a way to refresh this when the code runs?

Comment: Ah, after reading the jquery docs, the way to attach delegated event handlers is to attach them to a parent element (in this case `#infinite-container`) and provide an additional selector for the child elements that the event should trigger for . Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly now. It's only my second day of using jQuery so I got confused with this.

Comment: @AlphaDjango everyone starts somewhere :)